# Disecting flash script and figuring out parameters

Tags: flash

I have following swf script:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
//Frame 1
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
    function layout_stage() {
        sw = Stage.width;
        sh = Stage.height;
        center_obj(mcLoad);
        tool_pos();
    }
    function center_obj(x) {
        var _local3 = x._width;
        var _local2 = x._height;
        x._x = (sw - _local3) / 2;
        x._y = (sh - _local2) / 2;
    }
    function tool_pos() {
        var _local1 = mcTool._width;
        var _local2 = mcs[1][1]._height;
        mcTool._x = (sw - _local1) / 2;
        mcTool._y = sh - 50;
    }
    function start_engine() {
        setInterval(auto_rotate, 300);
        init_scroll();
    }
    function init_engine() {
        if ((!((passedVars = get_parameters()))) || (!varsTest())) {
            err_msg("Bad parameters specified!");
        } else {
            var _local4 = 1;
            while (_local4 <= Number(passedVars.rows)) {
                var _local6 = new Array();
                var _local2 = 1;
                while (_local2 <= Number(passedVars.cols)) {
                    var _local5 = ((_local4 - 1) * passedVars.cols) + _local2;
                    var _local3 = _root.createEmptyMovieClip((("img" + _local4) + "_") + _local2, img_z + _local5);
                    _local3._visible = false;
                    _local3.idn = _local5;
                    imgLoader.loadClip(((((passedVars.path + passedVars.fname) + "_") + fill_zero(_local2, 2)) + ".") + passedVars.fext, _local3);
                    _local6[_local2] = _local3;
                    _local2++;
                }
                mcs[_local4] = _local6;
                _local4++;
            }
            layout_stage();
            show_load(mcs[ypos][xpos], null);
            start_engine();
        }
    }
    function rotate_img(xStep, yStep) {
        var _local1 = mcs[ypos][xpos];
        xpos = xpos + xStep;
        ypos = ypos - yStep;
        if (ypos > passedVars.rows) {
            ypos = passedVars.rows;
        }
        if (ypos < 1) {
            ypos = 1;
        }
        if (xpos > Number(passedVars.cols)) {
            xpos = 1;
        }
        if (xpos < 1) {
            xpos = Number(passedVars.cols);
        }
        if (!mcs[ypos][xpos].loadOk) {
            show_load(mcs[ypos][xpos], _local1);
        } else {
            _local1._visible = false;
            center_obj(mcs[ypos][xpos]);
            mcs[ypos][xpos]._visible = true;
        }
        update_senzors();
        updateAfterEvent();
    }
    function auto_rotate() {
        if (((!dragging) && (mcs[ypos][xpos].loadOk)) && (auto_play != 0)) {
            rotate_img(auto_play, 0);
        }
    }
    function varsTest() {
        var _local1 = true;
        if (!passedVars.path) {
            _local1 = false;
        }
        if (!passedVars.cols) {
            _local1 = false;
        }
        if (!passedVars.rows) {
            passedVars.rows = 1;
        }
        if (!passedVars.type) {
            passedVars.type = "closed";
        }
        if (!passedVars.fname) {
            passedVars.fname = "seq";
        }
        if (!passedVars.fext) {
            passedVars.fext = "jpg";
        }
        if (!passedVars.autoplay) {
            auto_play = 1;
        } else {
            auto_play = Number(passedVars.autoplay);
        }
        return(_local1);
    }
    function fill_zero(num, pos) {
        var _local1 = "";
        _local1 = String(num);
        while (_local1.length < pos) {
            _local1 = "0" + _local1;
        }
        return(_local1);
    }
    function get_parameters() {
        var _local6 = _root._url;
        var _local7 = _local6.lastIndexOf("?");
        var _local4 = new Array();
        var _local3 = new Array();
        if (_local7 != -1) {
            var _local8 = _local6.substring(_local7 + 1, _local6.length);
            if (_local8 != "") {
                _local3 = _local8.split("&");
                for (var _local5 in _local3) {
                    var _local2 = _local3[_local5].split("=");
                    _local4[_local2[0]] = unescape(_local2[1]);
                }
                return(_local4);
            }
        } else {
            return(0);
        }
    }
    function c_echo(msg) {
        _root.txt_console = _root.txt_console + msg;
    }
    function err_msg(msg) {
        _root.errWnd.txt_msg = msg;
        _root.errWnd._visible = true;
        center_obj(_root.errWnd);
    }
    function show_load(mc, omc) {
        center_obj(_root.mcLoader);
        _root.mcLoader._visible = true;
        loaderForMC = mc;
        oldMC = omc;
    }
    function hide_load() {
        _root.mcLoader._visible = false;
        loaderForMC = null;
        oldMC._visible = false;
        oldMC = null;
    }
    function progress_load(lb, tb) {
        var _local2 = (100 * lb) / tb;
        _root.mcLoader.mcProgress._xscale = _local2;
        updateAfterEvent();
    }
    function update_senzors() {
        var _local1 = "";
        if (Number(passedVars.rows) > 1) {
            _local1 = ("[" + ypos) + "] ";
        }
        mcTool.txt_info = ((_local1 + xpos) + "/") + passedVars.cols;
        if (sliderDrag == 0) {
            mcTool.mcSlider._x = sliderMin + (xpos / sliderRatio);
        }
    }
    function init_scroll() {
        sliderRatio = Number(passedVars.cols) / sliderDif;
    }
    stop();
    var dataPath = "";
    errWnd._visible = false;
    mcLoader._visible = false;
    mcInfo._visible = false;
    mcTool._visible = false;
    mcInfo.swapDepths(1000);
    mcTool.swapDepths(999);
    mcLoader.swapDepths(998);
    logo.swapDepths(1001);
    var sw = Stage.width;
    var sh = Stage.height;
    Stage.scaleMode = "noScale";
    Stage.align = "TL";
    var resListener = new Object();
    resListener.onResize = function () {
        layout_stage();
    };
    Stage.addListener(resListener);
    var imgLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
    var loadedObjs = 0;
    var loadListener = new Object();
    loadListener.onLoadStart = function (mc) {
        mc.loadOk = false;
    };
    loadListener.onLoadProgress = function (mc, loadedBytes, totalBytes) {
        if (mc == loaderForMC) {
            progress_load(loadedBytes, totalBytes);
        }
    };
    loadListener.onLoadComplete = function (mc) {
        mc._visible = false;
        loadedObjs++;
        layout_stage();
        if (loadedObjs == 1) {
            mcTool._visible = true;
        }
    };
    loadListener.onLoadInit = function (mc) {
        mc.loadOk = true;
        if (mc == loaderForMC) {
            hide_load();
        }
        center_obj(mc);
        if (mc == mcs[ypos][xpos]) {
            mc._visible = true;
        }
    };
    loadListener.onLoadError = function (mc, err) {
        err_msg(("Error: " + err) + newline);
    };
    imgLoader.addListener(loadListener);
    var mcs = new Object();
    var pos = 1;
    var img_z = 10;
    var passedVars = new Array();
    var xpos = 1;
    var ypos = 1;
    var xcount;
    var ycount;
    var auto_play = 0;
    var dragging = 0;
    var xmouseStep = 32;
    var ymouseStep = 64;
    var oldx = _root._xmouse;
    var oldy = _root._ymouse;
    var mouseListener = new Object();
    mouseListener.onMouseWheel = function (delta) {
    };
    mouseListener.onMouseDown = function () {
        dragging = 1;
    };
    mouseListener.onMouseUp = function () {
        dragging = 0;
    };
    mouseListener.onMouseMove = function () {
        var _local2 = 0;
        var _local3 = 0;
        if (dragging == 1) {
            dragging = 2;
            oldx = _root._xmouse;
            oldy = _root._ymouse;
        }
        if ((dragging == 2) && (sliderDrag != 1)) {
            if ((_root._xmouse - oldx) < (-xmouseStep)) {
                _local2 = -1;
            }
            if ((_root._xmouse - oldx) > xmouseStep) {
                _local2 = 1;
            }
            if ((_root._ymouse - oldy) < (-ymouseStep)) {
                _local3 = -1;
            }
            if ((_root._ymouse - oldy) > ymouseStep) {
                _local3 = 1;
            }
            if ((_local2 != 0) || (_local3 != 0)) {
                rotate_img(_local2, _local3);
                oldx = _root._xmouse;
                oldy = _root._ymouse;
            }
        }
    };
    Mouse.addListener(mouseListener);
    var smallStep = 10;
    var k_frameUp = 38;
    var k_frameDown = 40;
    var k_frameLeft = 37;
    var k_frameRight = 39;
    var k_pause = 32;
    var k_play = 13;
    var k_exitWnd = 27;
    var keyListener = new Object();
    keyListener.onKeyDown = function () {
        switch (Key.getCode()) {
            case k_frameRight : 
                rotate_img(-1, 0);
                auto_play = 0;
                return;
            case k_frameLeft : 
                rotate_img(1, 0);
                auto_play = 0;
                return;
            case k_frameUp : 
                rotate_img(0, 1);
                auto_play = 0;
                return;
            case k_frameDown : 
                rotate_img(0, -1);
                auto_play = 0;
        }
    };
    keyListener.onKeyUp = function () {
        switch (Key.getCode()) {
            case k_play : 
                if (auto_play == 0) {
                    auto_play = 1;
                } else {
                    auto_play = -auto_play;
                }
                return;
            case k_pause : 
                auto_play = 0;
                return;
            case k_exitWnd : 
                getURL ("javascript: window.close()");
        }
    };
    Key.addListener(keyListener);
    var loaderForMC = null;
    var oldMC = null;
    var sliderMin = mcTool.mcSlider._x;
    var sliderMax = (mcTool.mcSlider._x + 88);
    var sliderDrag = 0;
    var sliderDif = (sliderMax - sliderMin);
    var sliderRatio;
    var oldSlidePos = sliderMin;
    mcTool.btnPause.onRelease = function () {
        auto_play = 0;
    };
    mcTool.btnExit.onRelease = function () {
        getURL ("javascript: window.close()");
    };
    mcTool.btnLeft.onRelease = function () {
        auto_play = -1;
    };
    mcTool.btnRight.onRelease = function () {
        auto_play = 1;
    };
    mcTool.btnFrameLeft.onRelease = function () {
        rotate_img(-1, 0);
        auto_play = 0;
    };
    mcTool.btnFrameRight.onRelease = function () {
        rotate_img(1, 0);
        auto_play = 0;
    };
    mcTool.btnWnd.onRelease = function () {
        if (_root.mcInfo._visible) {
            _root.mcInfo._visible = false;
        } else {
            center_obj(_root.mcInfo);
            _root.mcInfo._visible = true;
        }
    };
    mcTool.mcSlider.onPress = function () {
        this.startDrag(false, sliderMin, this._y, sliderMax, this._y);
        sliderDrag = 1;
    };
    mcTool.mcSlider.onRelease = function () {
        this.stopDrag();
        sliderDrag = 0;
    };
    mcTool.mcSlider.onEnterFrame = function () {
        var _local2 = Math.round((this._x - oldSlidePos) * sliderRatio);
        if ((sliderDrag == 1) && (_local2 != 0)) {
            rotate_img(_local2, 0);
        }
        oldSlidePos = this._x;
    };
    init_engine();

﻿
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
//Symbol 11 MovieClip Frame 1
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
    stop();

﻿
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
//Symbol 9 Button
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
on (release) {
    getURL ("javascript: window.close()");
}
```

and I need to figure out what should be the name of the file(ie. path to it), if I call the script like so:

script.swf?path=./&cols=36&fname=rotate

So, I know it's loading a flash movie from the same directory the script's in, but I can't seem to figure a way it's loading it, nor the movie name I need to use in order to load it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In case of the following request:

script.swf?path=./&cols=36&fname=rotate

script will look for images with filenames from rotate_1.jpg to rotate_36.jpg, and will then play those in frames.

As simple as that.